# Covariant derivative in Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to show that the covariant derivative when done in Euclidean space coincides with the standard differentiation of vector fields but I'm struggling to see here. I was trying to essentially compute the general Levi-Civita connection and conclude from there (i.e. if it did end up being the same we're done) but got pretty muddled even with this computation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: The metric coefficients in standard coordinates are all constants, and every term in the formula for the Christoffel symbols involves a derivative of a metric coefficient.

Comment: Ooh okay yes of course! Just so I know I'm understanding correctly, would the metric coefficients $g_{ij} =\delta_{ij} $, as g is the dot product?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.